# Flutter Local notifiaction background not working , getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider

Tags: flutter, localnotification

Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider

firebase_messaging: ^10.0.5

flutter_local_notifications: ^8.1.1+1

firebase_core: ^1.5.0

path_provider: ^2.0.2

Answer (score 0):

I think 3 simple steps will solve your issue.

1. flutter pub get
2. flutter clean
3. flutter run